# Attempt to present * on * whose view is not in the window hierarchy in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm trying to understand what is happening in here. I want to add a table view controller in a game to simply present the daily score. Now, that view is accessible from main menu by touching a SpriteNode.

```
if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == statistics
{
  let vc = self.view?.window?.rootViewController
  vc?.performSegueWithIdentifier("Statistics", sender: self)
}
```

Everything goes great for the first time. The table appears and is showing what it needs to. Now, from the tableview, by swiping to right I'm going back to my main menu:

```
if swipeGesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
{
      performSegueWithIdentifier("back", sender: self)
}
```

When I'm trying again to go again to the statistics tableview the app is blocked and I receive that warning: Attempt to present * on * whose view is not in the window hierarchy!. 
I guess that when is coming back from the statistics table, is going to the GameViewController.swift and only after that the MainMenu is presented.

```
if let scene = MainMenu.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? MainMenu {
   // Configure the view.
   let skView = self.view as SKView
   skView.showsFPS = false
   skView.showsNodeCount = false

   /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
   skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

   /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
   scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
   skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

Can anyone help? Many thanks.

Comment: Is the "back" segue an unwind segue?

Comment: No. It's simply a seague defined in Main.storyboard by dragging from Statistics TableviewController to GameViewController

Comment: Then you should change it to an unwind segue otherwise you will be creating an ever deepening series of view controllers

Comment: That was the solution. Thanks a lot.